# Бот вк. Получить chat_id текущей беседы

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, chat

цель - менять название беседы по команде.

```
if (message.getText().startsWith("название") || message.getText().startsWith("Название")){
                try {

                    String t = message.getText();
                    int space = t.indexOf(" ");
                    String newTitle = t.substring(space + 1);

                    vk.messages().editChat(group, chat_id, newTitle).execute();

                    vk.messages().send(group)
                            .peerId(message.getPeerId())
                            .randomId(random.nextInt())
                            .message("Название изменено на " + newTitle)
                            .execute();

                }catch (Exception e){

                    vk.messages().send(group)
                            .peerId(message.getPeerId())
                            .randomId(random.nextInt())
                            .message("Ошибка")
                            .execute();

                }

            }
```

метод editChat() принимает в качестве параметра GroupActor, chat_id и новый заголовок. Вопрос: как получить этот самый chat_id беседы, в которой происходит действие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если поискать в документации, то можно прийти, например, сюда - https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Пролистав вниз видно это:

[image: скриншот]

Если изучить Ваш код, то у вас уже есть тот самый `peer_id` (`message.getPeerId()`).

Вам остается только вычесть 2000000000 и Вы получите `chat_id`.

```
vk.messages().editChat(group, message.getPeerId()-2000000000, newTitle).execute();
```